# network latency in vaadin applications

Tags: vaadin

I am planning to use vaadin to develop internal application, which will be used in high volume and accessed from offices spread around globe. The choice of vaadin stems out from the fact that it would make development of application easier and I don't need to worry about frontend coding. However, I am a little concerned that since all events are sent to the application server, and since the users would be accessing from globe, so can the network latency be a big issue in the responsiveness of application to support high volume throughput. The application is going to be used in high volume by 100-500 users per day. Any insights from previous deployments/experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a study made by Vaadin about the scalability. I hope these links will help you make the decision.

https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-scalability-study-quicktickets
http://www.slideshare.net/codento/vaadin-scalabilityslides

Answer (score 1):

I use vaadin over the Internet but my server is in the same country. So I can't tell you how the application behaves over the globe, but I can say that vaadin is super fast within my connection. No difference between local / Internet!